# Find circles that intersects a point

Tags: node.js, mongodb, geolocation, geojson

I'm getting in trouble when I try to run this code on mongodb

```
var partners = db.partners.find({})
var kmToRadius = function(km){
    var earthRadiusInKm = 6378.1;
    return km / earthRadiusInKm;
}
db.runCommand({
    $centerSphere: [ [partners.loc], kmToRadius(partners.km) ] :{
        $geoIntersects:{
            $geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ -73.93414657, 40.82302903 ] }

            }
    }
})
```

What I'm trying to do is get all the partners location (which are in geojson format), make a circle using $centerSphere and verify if there is intersection with a coordinate.

I know I can't store circles in GeoJson format, only polygons, which turns very difficult to do what I want. Someone knows if there is another way to make this work ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My partners collection seems like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("583315cfa9d41218cc9c833f"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2016-11-21T15:42:07.703Z"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-11-21T15:42:07.703Z"),
    "name" : "partnerName",
    "mainEmail" : "email",
    "password" : "$2a$10$WJC6WzZNM8NyDKQgovJa.OICLOMV6Qp6xcGLE3fRcUGuBa8Zhy8qy",
    "km" : 10,
    "loc" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [ 
            -46.62217, 
            -23.668224
        ]
    },
    "rate" : 4,
    "nServices" : 35
}
```

But what I want to do is create a radius for each partner and check which partners intersects a point, instead of get the partners within a radius.